# Loadhtmlfile and echo certain part

Tags: php

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=1&appid=570&market_hash_name=Goldhorn");
echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

it echos

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"$2.70","volume":"870","median_price":"$2.62"}
```

i only want the $2.70 part to be echoed. How would i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an HTML parser (DOMDocument) for this, it returns a JSON string, use `json_decode()` for this:

```
$url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=1&appid=570&market_hash_name=Goldhorn';
$contents = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
echo $contents['lowest_price'];
```

Comment: @DanielAguilar sure glad this shed some lighrt